# Mocking locations on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I'm attempting to create a simple app to mock GPS coordinates.
I have setup the correct permissions in manifest.
The problem is actually mocking the address.
I have tested the following code with no success:

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
ll = new MyLocationListener();
if (lm.getProvider("Test") == null) {
    lm.addTestProvider("Test", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 0, 1);
}
lm.setTestProviderEnabled("Test", true);
lm.requestLocationUpdates("Test", 0, 0, ll);

map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng l) {
        Location loc = new Location("Test");
        loc.setLatitude(l.latitude);
        loc.setLongitude(l.longitude);
        loc.setAltitude(0); 
        loc.setAccuracy(10f);
        loc.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(System.nanoTime());
        loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
        lm.setTestProviderLocation("Test", loc);
    }
};
```

I have also attempted to use `FusedLocationApi` which does work for any apps using the google framework. Google maps, for example, works perfectly fine.

Although the problem I have found with `FusedLocationApi` is that it does not mock the location for any apps outside of the Google framework which is a problem. Apps outside the google framework generally report that "No GPS is being detected".

I really hope someone can guide me in the right direction!

Comment: Marshmallow need runtime permissions instead of manifest, so do you have code for that or not check it

Comment: I do, otherwise fusedlocationapi would not work.